# Attribute Error to send pictures on a FTP server with Python and ftplib

Tags: python, ftp, attributeerror, ftplib

I'm actually trying to send pictures(.jpg) saved on a directory of my computer to a FTP server with a python script and ftplib .
The path where are the images is : "D:/directory_image".
I use python 2.7 and the command .storbinary from ftplib to send .jpg.
Despite my search, I get an error message that I can't resolve :

```
`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'storbinary'
```

Here's the part of my code that cause problems :

```
from ftplib import FTP
import time
import os

ftp = FTP('Host')
connect= ftp.login('user', 'passwd')
path = "D:/directory_image"
FichList = os.listdir( path )
i = len(FichList)
u = 0

While u < i :
    image_name= FichList[u]
    jpg_to_send = path + '/' + image_name
    file_open = open (image_name, 'rb')
    connect.storbinary('STOR '+ jpg_to_send, file_open)
    file_open.close()
    u = u + 1
```

I know that the file argument in Storbinary () must be an open file object instead of a string... But it's an open file object in my script, isn't it?

Thanks a lot,

Clara

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
from ftplib import FTP
import time
import os

session = FTP('Host', 'user', 'passwd')
path = "D:/directory_image"
FichList = os.listdir( path )


for image_name in FichList:                         #Iterate Each File
    jpg_to_send = os.path.join(path, image_name)    #Form full path to image file
    file_open = open(jpg_to_send, 'rb')
    session.storbinary('STOR '+ image_name, file_open)
    file_open.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
connect= ftp.login('user', 'passwd')
```

`ftp.login()` returns a string with the login result (ie "230 Login successful")

so here:

```
connect.storbinary('STOR '+ jpg_to_send, file_open)
```

you're trying to call `storbinary` on a string... The fix is easy:

```
ftp.storbinary('STOR '+ jpg_to_send, file_open)
```

As a side note: you want to make sure your files are closed whatever happens, so replace this:

```
file_open = open (image_name, 'rb')
ftp.storbinary('STOR '+ jpg_to_send, file_open)
file_open.close()
```

with:

```
with open(image_name, 'rb') as file_open:
    ftp.storbinary('STOR '+ jpg_to_send, file_open)
```

and the file will be automagically closed when exiting the `with` block, whatever happens.